# Extract the ip's that have selfsign certificate in the SSL session by tshark or wireshark

Tags: ssl, wireshark, self-signed, tshark

I am working on a pcap file that captured a lot of packet and i want extract ip's that have self signed certificate in the SSL session.
i don't know what is difference between self signed certificate or signed certificate in packets.
 i think wireshark or tshark can do this.
I just found this command to display certificates in tshark.

tshark -nr sampleTraffic.pcap -2 -R "ssl.handshake.certificate" -V

but how can i separate ip's that have self signed certificate in the SSL session

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But for "i don't know what is difference between self signed certificate or signed certificate" the answer is: nothing. All certificates are signed by another certificate, but this second certificate can be the same as the one being signed, this is the case of all self signed certificates.

Comment: Agree with @PatrickMevzek. This is off-topic here. You should ask this on Server Fault or the Information Security stackexchange.